# Don`t show fetched Data immadiately

Tags: extjs, touch

I am looking for the oppurtunity to change fetched data from server, before making it visible.

I have a callback function with is called after proxy (jsonp) loaded the data. The problem is
the unedited data is visible for a short time until my callback edits it and refresh the store with
setData(myEditedData).

How can I say the store: "Hey, please load the data, but dont make it visible!"?

I have configured my store as follows:

```
Ext.define('TaskManager.store.TaskStore', { extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : { proxy : { type : 'jsonp', url : 'http://bla.bla', reader : { type : 'json', rootProperty : 'data' } } },

load : function(options, scope) { 
// Load datas 
},

callback : function(success, response) { 
var editedData = []; 
// Edit data from server, for example remove html entities, ...
this.setData(editedData); } });
```

There is the problem. The proxy sets the recieved data immadiately into the view. Until my callback function is finished it is visible for a short time :-( I just want only make my editedData visible in the view.

I hope my explanation was clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the store load event, or whichever event results from the action you are using to fetch your data (e.g 'add' etc) have you tried either `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.stopEvent()`, where e is the event object passed to the listener?